# Find the parametrization of the curve resulting from intersection of two surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

The question reads as follows:

Find a parametrization of the curve resulting from the intersection of the surfaces:

$z = x^2 - y^2$ and $z= x^2 +xy - 1$

My attempt:

(*Use y = t as a parameter, so solve for y*)

$z = x^2-y^2$ and $y^2 = \frac{(z-x^2+1)^2}{x^2}$

so we have $x^2y^2 = (-y^2+1)^2$

$xy = -y^2+1$ then $x = -y + \frac{1}{y}$

then we also have $z = (\frac{-y+1}{y})^2 - y^2$

so $z = \frac{y^2 -2y + 1}{y^2} - y^2$

$z = 1 - \frac{2}{y} + \frac{1}{y^2} - y^2$

now let $y = t$ be the parameter so we have:

$\langle - t + \frac{1}{t},\ t, \ 1 - \frac{2}{t} + \frac{1}{t^2} - t^2 \rangle$

However, I have no idea if this is **a** [*Deleted: the*] correct parametric curve. Any thoughts?

Edit: after looking over my working I realized I made an algebra mistake. I have checked the following parametric equation and it seems correct:

$\langle - t + \frac{1}{t},\ t, \ - 2 + \frac{1}{t^2} \rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea if this is the correct parametric curve.

The word "the" is not appropriate, here. Any given curve can have many different sets of parametric equations. So, the question is whether this is **a** correct parametric equation.

To check that your answer is correct, just substitute back in the equations of the two surfaces. The point $\big(x(t), y(t), z(t)\big)$ given by your parametric equations should satisfy both surface equations for all values of $t$.

There's another slightly subtle point, though ...
If you do what I said above, then you have shown that your equations represent some **subset** of the intersection, but maybe not all of it. It quite often happens that the intersection of two surfaces consists of two or more disconnected pieces. For example, think of the two loops formed when a small cylinder intersects a larger one at right angles. Any given set of parametric equations can represent one of the pieces, but not more than one. So, to be thorough, you really ought to show that every point on the intersection will be given by some value of $t$ in your equations. But this is maybe more than you were expected to do in this question.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I checked by substituting back in the equations, but it seems my equations  do not satisfy both surface equations. How would you approach this question?

Comment: The approach you took is quite reasonable. I suspect you just made a simple algebra error somewhere.

Comment: Okay I'll give it another try, thanks!

Comment: I just checked over my calculations, I did in fact make an algebra mistake, see my edit for a correct parametrization.

Comment: OK. Good. But, f you want to be thorough, bear in mind what I said in the last paragraph of my answer. You have shown that your equation describes *some portion* of the intersection, but maybe not all of it.

Comment: I see what you mean, for example my parametric equation is undefined for y = t = 0, which doesn't seem to be the case in the original equations. I assume to make sure it describes the entire curve I would have to go over the domain piece by piece?

Comment: If $y=t=0$, then $z=x^2$ on one surface, and $z=x^2+1$ on the other one. So, the original intersection curve also does not include any points where $y=0$. So, no problem there. But there might be problems in other places. As you say, you have to hunt around. For clues, use some software to plot the original curve and your parametric one.